# How to change a bath plug chain?

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, chain

I have been looking around for a tutorial to chane a simple bath plug chain. My chain has snapped, so the plug is not connected. I assumed it would be a simple job, but i can't find anything online about it.

Is it just a case of opening the "8" loops with a pair of pliers and the tightening them again? This is the plug I have:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where it snapped. If the '8s' just pulled apart, then yes, bend it closed again around the anchor it pulled off of. If the ball chain broke and one part is long enough, remove the connector between the '8' and the ball chain and remove the short piece and insert the longer piece then reassemble. You can also get a connector that attaches two ends of the ball chain or just get a fresh new length of ball chain.